# Network error when scaffolding with working connection string

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a connection string to a SQL Server DB.

This connection string works fine when used in the application.
It also works fine when used in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

It fails with a network error when I try to use it to do DB-first approach scaffolding with entity framework via `Scaffold-DbContext`

```
 A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
```

I'm not sure what to do here since the connection string works in other contexts.

The connection string looks like this:

```
"Data Source=dbserver\\db01;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password; Connect Timeout=60;Connection Timeout=60;Connection Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
```

This is probably from a VPN that is required to connect to the DB. VS is probably not using the VPN properly when trying to connect.

How do I troubleshoot this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

This is the issue
dbserver\\db01;

That second slash is a string escape sequence.

It's not needed here and removing it solves the issue.

So it should be

dbserver\db01;